# Error when Install Bundle to add Devise Auth to Ruby Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, bundle-install

So i'm new to Ruby On Rails and i found this problem when i try to add Devise to my Project.

Here is the Error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJ1D.png)

And Here is my GemFile :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Izz.png)

**My Version :**

Ruby : ruby 3.1.1p18

Rails : Rails 7.0.2.2

Gem : 3.3.8

Any Idea what should i do to fix this problem?

Note : Already change ruby version on my Gem File same as my Ruby Version, but meet this problem. (Cannot Bundle Install if i not change my Ruby Version on Gem File)

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)". We need to see your code and the error _in the question itself_. Links rot then break, and images can't be reused to help test and formulate answers, so, to help us help you, remove the images and replace them with their text equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've installed Ruby without DevKit. [Here](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) you can find proper one.

PS.
Personally I strongly recommend doing any Ruby development under [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) and with usage of [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: I already installed the lastest Ruby+Devkit 3.1.1-1 (x64) version on my PC and still doesn't solved the problem sir. Any kind other solution that can i do?